# Insert many rows in a table with multiple columns having data in sequence but the columns are not INT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to insert many rows in a table with multiple columns having data in sequence but the columns are not INT. I need to insert data into an existing table as shown below. Please help.

Ex.

```
ID    ItemID    Value    Description    Active
1      2         A1       A101           1
2      2         A2       A102           1
3      2         A3       A103           1
....
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

You need to `cast` to `int`

```
SELECT CAST(varchar_column_name AS INT) FROM Table
```

Comment: The question might be bad, but it contains the word "insert" three times and I can not find "select" in the question.

Comment: @ceving Since the question 'might be' bad, I didn't feel like spoon feeding him. I showed him the road to walk upon. :)